# Multiple select tags (v-for) with the same v-model

Tags: select, vue.js, v-model

I am having multiple selects with the same `v-model` and would like to display value of each select separately. Do I need to bind `:key`?

Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq0w8d3v/)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by using the same `v-model` for each select, but also wanting each select to have a separate value? That's contradictory.

Comment: I am having many select inputs and I don't think it is correct to give its own `v-model` for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind different values to each select, then it's easiest if you structure your data model such that every item in the array is an object with properties for the label and value, like this:

```vue
<li v-for="(item, index) in array">
  {{ item.label }}
  <select v-model="item.value" :key="index">
    <option>false</option>
    <option>true</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

```es6
data: {
  array: [
    {
      label: 'one',
      value: true,
    },
    {
      label: 'two',
      value: false,
    }
  ]
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq0w8d3v/4/)